# deploy mvc2 application to IIS7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7

Do I need to create a application pool which supports .net framework 4.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will depend on the framework version your MVC application is targeting. So if you application is targeting .NET 4.0 the application pool must be set to use CLR 4.0. If your application is targeting .NET 3.5 the application pool must be set to use CLR 2.0. Here's [an article](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNETMVC/216_Hosting_and_Deployment_of_an_ASPNET_MVC_Application_in_IIS6_and_IIS7.aspx) covering the various deployment scenarios.